# NoMethodError in Posts#show can't show user name in comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
<div class='comment'>
  <p>
    <%= comment.comment %>
    <%= comment.user.email %>
  </p>
```

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :user_name
      t.string :full_name
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
----------------------------------------------------------

class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:comment))
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id 
    @comment.save

    if @comment.save
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end

    -------------------

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end

    -------------------

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
  validates :user, :presence => true
  validates :title, :presence => true, length: { maximum: 25}, uniqueness: true
  validates :content, :presence => true
end
    -------------------
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password 

  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments

  def admin? 
    self.role == 'admin' 
  end

  def moderator? 
   self.role == 'moderator' 
  end

  validates :user_name,  :presence => true, uniqueness: true
  validates :full_name, :presence => true
  validates :password, :presence => true
  validates :email, :presence => true, uniqueness: true
end

     --------------------

class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.text :comment
      t.references :post, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

It says `undefined method user_name`

You can say that the comments may have been created without a user_id but thats not true cause if i write `<%= comment.user_id %>` it displays the correct user id. Also all of the comment have user id.
If you could please help cause i have looked up a lot of documentation but found nothing.

Comment: Exactly when do you get the error 'undefined method user_name'?

Comment: can you paste the full error?

Comment: I get the error when i enter a post where the comments are displayed(i get the error even on posts with no errors though)

Comment: NoMethodError in Posts#show
Showing C:/Ruby21-x64/rails/GamePageApp/app/views/comments/_comment.html where line #4 raised:

undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/posts/show.html

Rails.root: C:/Ruby21-x64/rails/GamePageApp

Answer (score 1):

Because Comment essence hasn't user_name, the user has it, so you can try sth like:

```
comment.user.user_name
```

Or better idea, add this:

```
delegate :user_name, to: :user
```

to your comment model and then you will be able to use `comment.user_name` as well.

Your variant:
1) add this into Comment model

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
```

2) add strong attributes for user in your Comment controller(where is code like params.require.permit):

```
  , user_attributes: %i(user_name full_name email password)
```

3) in your view

```
  <%= fields_for :user, @comment.user do |user_fields| %>
    <% user_fields.text_field :user_name %>
    <% user_fields.text_field :full_name %>
    <% user_fields.text_field :email %>
    <% user_fields.text_field :password %>
  <% end %>
```

4) try to save it in the end :)

Comment: It doesn't work Comment#user_name delegated to user.user_name, but user is nil: #<Comment id: nil, comment: nil, post_id: 18, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

Comment: @HansiCollaku where are you trying to call it ?

Comment: I call the user name in the _comment.html file which is displayed inside the show.html of the post

Comment: @HansiCollaku Do you mean partial for creating new comment ?

Comment: @HansiCollaku And you are using user_name in your form like an input ?

Comment: Now I see, you cant use it this way, because your Comment model hasn't such field, if you want to create new user during comment creation you should read about http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

And if you want to use user from a list, you should build a select with collection of users.

Comment: @HansiCollaku just let me know what do you want: create new user during comment creation or select one from persisted users ?

Comment: I just want to display the user_name of the user that created the comment